# Which of these reactants will not generate this racemic amine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, organic-reduction

[image]

I understand that in E there is no electrophile the amine can attack, however, I do not understand why A is an answer as well. The amine in A can perform an intramolecular attack on the aldehyde and form the product below. Why can it not?

Also, how does the oxygen leave anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of reductive amination, which generally proceeds through two main steps: (i) condensation reaction between the amine and carbonyl to generate an imine; and (ii) reduction of the imine to the corresponding amine.

[image]

Clearly (e) can't do this reaction since there is no carbonyl. The reason why (a) is also an answer comes down to the wording of the question - it specifically states that the product is racemic. The stereocentre in (a) is (*R*) in the starting material, and is not involved in the reaction so the product will exist as a single (*R*) enantiomer.

Comment: In the question, all the amides are secondary. Secondary amines can't form imines, thus how is an imine formed?

Comment: Fair point, they will just form iminium ions rather than imines, but the mechanism remains exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, ok. That explains the -1 charge then in the picture.